# How to configure meteor app creation folder structure

Tags: meteor, meteor-react

I would like to ask how do we configure or modify the default behavior of Meteor create app.

I only need to add my own folders automatically whenever I use Meteor create, so I don't have to add manually or delete the files that I don't need every single time.

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 in WSL

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible to create a custom structure and add it to a "meteor create" command. However, I'm not completely certain.

Instead, you can create an empty meteor app with the --bare flag, customize your structure to be as simple and standard as possible, and push it to a git repository, along with the .meteor folder.
Afterward, you can clone this new repository and begin with your custom meteor application structure as many times as you want.

Does this solution work for you?